# STM32 as I2C slave with Arduino/Jetson

Tags: stm32, i2c

I'd like to operate an STM32 MCU as a I2C slave connected to a Jetson AGX, such that the Jetson can use i2cdetect, i2cset, i2cget commands for scanning the i2c bus exposed by the STM, and also writing/reading basic register data.

**HW Description**
An STM32 NUCLEO-G071RB development board is used to function as I2C slave.
Pins are wired correctly using jumper cables, connecting GND, SCL and SDA from the nucleo board to pins 3, 5 and 9 on the [AGX](https://jetsonhacks.com/nvidia-jetson-agx-xavier-gpio-header-pinout/) 40-pin header.

**SW Description**
The jetson is running a standard JetPack with Ubuntu 18.04 (JetPack 4.6.0).
A project was created using STMCube IDE and configured as follows:

- Connectivity -> I2C 1
  Designating GPIO pins PB8 as SCL, and PB9 as SDA, both with pull-up and maximum speed set to very high.

The corresponding generated code for initializing the I2C channel is (slave address 0x20 and 100 KHz I2C speed):

```
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x00303D5B;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 40;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}
```

After initialization in *main*, the while loop simply does the following (*buf* is 2 byte array):

```
switch (hi2c1.State)
{
case HAL_I2C_STATE_READY:
  /*!< Peripheral Initialized and ready for use  */
  status = HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, buf, 2, 1000);
  if (status == HAL_OK)
      status = HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit(&hi2c1, buf, 2, 1000);
  break;
};
```

**Further Steps**

- At the beginning the voltage level wasn't matched so each i2c call in STM resulted in an acknowledge failure
- After matching the voltage level to 3.3V, the STM reports the ready state
- Within *HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive*, there are calls that wait for an address flag to be set

```
/* Enable Address Acknowledge */
hi2c->Instance->CR2 &= ~I2C_CR2_NACK;

/* Wait until ADDR flag is set */
if (I2C_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_ADDR, RESET, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
{
  /* Disable Address Acknowledge */
  hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_NACK;
  return HAL_ERROR;
}
```

But *I2C_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout* fails with a timeout error, while certainly the Jetson is trying to communicate using i2cdetect during that time (scanning the appropriate bus #8 *sudo i2cdetect -y -r 8*), which doesn't provide any successful output.

Is this the correct approach?
Just to mention that the check for address flag is a very preliminary one, regardless if data being sent or received.
Any insights would be valuable.

Thanks,
Moti.

Comment: See [How to create an I2C slave device](https://community.st.com/s/article/how-to-create-an-i2c-slave-device-using-the-stm32cube-library).

Comment: @hcheung thank you, this indeed made it work. What is the difference between the two modes and why interrupt mode made it work compared to a blocking operation?

Comment: You may want to read [AN2824](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00209826-stm32f10xxx-i-c-optimized-examples-stmicroelectronics.pdf). "In slave mode, it is not recommended to use polling mode, especially for handling the ADDR event because the slave doesn’t know in advance when it will be addressed by the Master... the application, which normally does other tasks and not just I2C communication, may get stuck waiting for the ADDR flag to be set. The same is true for the other events, for example the slave could also get stuck waiting for the RXNE or TXE flag to be set".

Comment: If you really want to do polling, you should check the STOPF flag (Stop received flag) when the transmitter sent the stop...

Comment: It perfectly makes sense for a robust application, I was hoping the simple mechanism will work as a sanity measure in polling mode. Thanks!